# Show div element when button is clicked before the form is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show a spinner div element on my page when user clicks submit button. There seems to be a bug in my code as I checked multiple answers and suggestions here for similar problems and nothing seems to work - on click console message is shown and the page starts reloading without showing the div element.

HTML:

```
<form action="/uploader" id="upload_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server">
  ...
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type = "submit" id="upload_button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" /> 
  </div>
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#upload_form').on('submit', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('.sk-cube-grid').show();
     console.log('Upload button was clicked');
     this.submit();
  });
});
```

I also tried without success :

```
$('#upload_button').on('click', function(e) { 
   console.log('Clicked on upload form');
   $('.sk-cube-grid').show();
});
```

EDIT: when I remove this.submit(); the spinner is shown after click but the form is not submitted - so CSS seems to be fine. Also, upload takes several seconds before page is reloaded so I have time to see the messages on console and verify that no spinner is shown...

Comment: hard to say as you do not provide the full code, I see not element of class 'sk-cube-grid'. One quick debug you can do is run this in the console: $('.sk-cube-grid').show(); see if that renders the desired effect. Also keep in mind htat your form now reloads the page so you will be redirected right away and might not have time to see the spinner

Comment: remove the `this.submit()` in form submit .Its not a valid syntax of jquery submit

Comment: Showing spinner is pointless action when you submit a from. Because submitting a form always reload the page or redirect page and spinner does not have enough time to be shown.

Comment: @prasad : what would be a correct syntax for form submit after preventing default action? When I remove this.submit() the spinner is shown, but I would need also to submit the form.

Comment: @IvonaTau `$(this).submit()` is the correct form .But you apply inside the form submit without any condition .It have loop effect ,submit the form again and again. if you have any condition for before `this.submit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works. But the message quickly disappear becouse a new page is rendered.

```js
$('.sk-cube-grid').hide();
$('#upload_form').on('submit', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('.sk-cube-grid').show();
     console.log('Upload button was clicked');
     var form = this;
     setTimeout( function () { 
       form.submit();
     }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/7914637" id="upload_form" method="GET">
  <p>...</p>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type = "submit" id="upload_button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" /> 
  </div>
</form>
<div class="sk-cube-grid">My hide message</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer , but my problem seems to be elsewhere as form submit triggers additional code that is running for several seconds (that is why I need a spinner :) ) and I am able to verify that it has not appeared...

Comment: @IvonaTau, I append timeout function. The **My hide message** will be visible during 3 seconds after form submitted. Try to run the snippet again.

Comment: thanks, adding a short timeout works indeed - spinner appears and continues to be shown while form is submitting

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should make an additional submit button that is hidden and is being pressed automatically by JavaScript after an interval that the spinner should have been shown.
Code:

```
<form action="/uploader" method="POST">
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="showSpinner()">
<div id="loading"></div>
<input type="submit" style="visibility: hidden" id="submit">
<script>
function showSpinner() {
document.getElementById("loading").style = "background: blue";
document.getElementById("animation").innerHTML = 
'@keyframes loading {
100% { background: red; }
}';
setTimeout(redirect, 2000)
}
function redirect() {
document.getElementById("submit").click();
}
</script>
<style>
#loading {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
animation: loading 2s linear infinite;
</style>
<style id="animation"></style>
```

You can increase the setTimeout to fit your spinner, or if you use percentage, make it redirect when it's 100%.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make a check before confirmation like:

```
 $(function() {

   $('#upload_button').on('click', function(e) { 
   if (confirm("Click OK to continue?")){
       $('form').submit();
    }
   else
   {
     e.preventDefault();
   }});
 });
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Can you let me know for -1?

Comment: Thanks for answer @Sunny, but the answer does not solve showing the spinner while upload takes place

Comment: it's not me who downvoted as I don't even have enough points to do that :) @Sunny